# How to convert a folder of files with GDAL TRANSFER?

Tags: cmd, windows-10, gdal

I have about 2000 images that need to be converted from `TIF` to `JPG` with some parameters using `GDAL`. I need to achieve this by using a `CMD` script. Here is my script so far:

```
set "SourceFolder=C:\Tif\newimages\"
set "DestinationFolder=C:\Tif\temp"
set "CreatedFolder="

if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" (
    md "%DestinationFolder%" 2>nul
    if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" (
        echo Error: Failed to create folder "%DestinationFolder%"
        goto EndBatch
    )
    set "CreatedFolder=1"
)
for %%N in (%SourceFolder%*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of jpeg -a_nodata 0 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 %%i %DestinationFolder%\%%i*jpg

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

This produces the following error message on `CMD`:

```
ERROR 4: %i: No such file or directory
```

Background:

Windows environment (obviously)
OSGeo4W cmd to run the script.

What I am looking for is an explanation of what I am doing wrong with the script and suggestions to make it functional.

Edit:

I realize that the commands at the end of the `gdal` line should be source and destinations of converted files. Is there any way around this as I would need to only define the destination folder at the end. I got it to work as an endless loop which was not optimal of course as the number of images is more than 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after closer inspection, it turns out that I set a value for `%%N` and later tried to use `%%i`. Also, the `gdal` command should be this:

```
DO gdal_translate -of jpeg -a_nodata 0 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 %%N %DestinationFolder%\%%~nN.jpg
```

Instead of:

```
DO gdal_translate -of jpeg -a_nodata 0 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 %%i %DestinationFolder%\%%i*jpg
```

Comment: you should enclose path\filenames in quotes to properly handle spaces or other poison characters in foldernames or filenames: `DO gdal_translate -of jpeg -a_nodata 0 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 "%%N" "%DestinationFolder%\%%~nN.jpg"`

Comment: Thank you @Stephan. This does also make easier to read long scripts.